# matplotlib ticklabels disabling co-ordinates from displaying, twinx/twiny functions any useful?

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

I went through tcaswell's answer on stackoverflow for the question on looking at co-ordinate information after using xticklabels/yticklabels function: http://goo.gl/0Y5VpF that "there is no easy way to do this." I am curious if the job becomes any easier if I had twin axes. (PS: I am newbie to python :) )

e.g. I have a figure in which I have used twinx() + set_yticklabels() functions like this:

```
bx2=bx.twinx()
bx2.set_ylim(bx.get_ylim())   
bx2.set_yticks(new_tick_locations)   
bx2.set_yticklabels(mylabellist)
```

I no longer able to see y-position of the cursor in the interactive plot window. Kindly let me know if I could make figure window to look at co-ordinates corresponding to bx axis, so that one can readily look at y co-ordinate upon mouse over.

Thanks,
sahdeV

Comment: Your link is dead.  If you just paste the SO link in it will auto-magic the url to look nice.

Comment: edited now, I was missing space between  "http://goo.gl/0Y5VpF" and "that"

Comment: any answer anybody? @tcaswell??

Comment: My answer is the same as what it was, 'there is no easy way'.  By using `set_yticklabels` you are using a `FixedFormatter` which means your tick labels are _completely_ disconnected from your data.  The `Formatter` machinery is what is used to generate the text for the y-position.